# jQuery - How to Delay between effects?

Tags: jquery, delay

I'm simply trying to delay an action before it starts but I seem to be having some trouble.

**This is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".action1").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeOut('slow'); });
    $(".action2").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn('slow'); });
});
```

And I basically want to delay the first action from taking place just for a few seconds (onLoad).

Comment: I'm aware of it, I'm just not 100% were to place it in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this(added delay for the first element before fadeOut call):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".action1").bind("load", function () { $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow'); }); //Delay for 2 seconds
    $(".action2").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn('slow'); });
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Worked great, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

try using the `delay()` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".action1").bind("load", function () { $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow'); });
    $(".action2").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn('slow'); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout ( expression, timeout );`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function calls in [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
setTimeout( func, delay );

setTimeout(function() {
    /* your code */
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```